# Target Unreachable, 'user' returned null

Tags: java, jsf

I have created a method to add and I used the jsf and hibarnate framwork but a notable exception appear and she blocked me.

the code View:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="Prenom: "
            style="font-size:15px; font-family:verdana;" />
        <p:inputText value="#{Bean.user.prenom}" style="width:201px; height:20px; font-size:15px;" />

        <h:outputLabel value="Nom: "
            style="font-size:15px; font-family:verdana;" />
        <p:inputText value="#{Bean.user.nom}" style="width:201px; height:20px; font-size:15px;" />
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{Bean.saveUser()}" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

the code bean manager is :

```
@ManagedBean(name="Bean")
@RequestScoped
@Component
public class UserManager{
@Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    private User user;


    public UserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void saveUser(){
        userService.add(user);

    }

}
```

When I submit the form I get this error

```
Etat HTTP 500 - /pages/test.xhtml @13,102 value="#{Bean.user.prenom}": Target Unreachable, 'user' returned null
```

. Can you help me to find the problem

Comment: you need to initialize the attributes in the constructor.
something like `setUser(new User());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `@Autowired` annotation for each field you want to autowire.

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@Autowired
private User user;
```

If you don't want `user` to be autowired, you must initialize it somewhere (i.e. in the constructor), as the `inputText` will call `user.getPrenom()` and `user.getNom()`.

Comment: not match when in add the user.getPrenom in my view and when i add the annotation @Autowired in user a error appear

Comment: @khadija I don't understand what you just wrote... Can you please explain?

Comment: @khadija I gave you two suggestions. The first is to autowire the user, the second is to initialize it. Which of the two doesn't work?

Comment: @khadija It's impossible. If you initialize the user, it **can't** be null, so your error must disappear. Try adding this to your class: `public UserManager() { this.user = new User(); }`